# Ring structure of coinvariant of $W(U(4))$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lie-groups, invariant-theory

I want to know the ring structure of the coinvariant of $W(U(4))$, where $W(G)$ is the Weyl group of G.

I know that the ring structure of the coinvariant of $W(U(3))$ is $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ with the following relations:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0, \quad x_1.x_2 + x_2.x_3 + x_1.x_3 = 0,\quad  x_1.x_2.x_3 = 0.$$

If you have any reference for this please introduce me.
Thank you so much for your responses.

Comment: By definition, the coinvariant ring is the quotient of the polynomial ring by the invariant functions of positive degree. So you get something similar with $n=4$, modding out by elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Panyushev’s notes are a good source: https://math.uchicago.edu/~margalit/repthy/lecturesRT.pdf.